# Alternative design to avoid dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, oop, dynamic-cast

Say I have `Archive` interface and `File` interface.

- Each `File` is guaranteed to have at least `std::string name`.
- Each `Archive` can `std::vector<File*> Archive::list() const` its files.
- Each `Archive` can `Archive::extract(std::vector<File*> files)`.

Then I have `ZipArchive` and `ZipFile`, `ZipFile` contains offset in the archive file and other implementation details. Then there's `TarArchive`/`TarFile` and so on. Each of these fills `std::vector<File*> list() const` with instances of `ZipFile`, `TarFile` etc.

`list()` is meant to give users a chance to select which files to unpack. They select elements from that vector, then they pass this vector to `extract()`.

At this point, the `ZipArchive` needs to assume it was passed the right type and do `dynamic_cast<ZipFile*>(file)` to access implementation details.

This feels bad. Is this acceptable? Are there alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean that `ZipArchive` has a method like `ZipArchive::unpack(ZipFile & file)`?

Comment: It could have, but I don't see how it changes anything.

Comment: What if you change `extract` to take a set of indexes rather than `File*`s?

Comment: Why does `File` need to be an interface?

Comment: If semantics of polymorphic part in `extract` are common in various `Archive` (i.e. they just call `XXXArchive::unpack(XXXFile & file)`), how about define `XXXFile::call_unpacker(Archive *)`?

Comment: "What if you change extract to take a set of indexes rather than File*s?" I thought about this as well, but that sounds very inelegant and I bet more issues are going to arise in the future. "Why does File need to be an interface?" I come from C# background and it like a felt right thing to do. Now I'm not so sure.

Comment: `XXXFile::call_unpacker(Archive *)` doesn't this inverse responsibility for unpacking from archive to the files, and increase memory usage?

Comment: @rr C# or C++ the concept of interface does not change. I think the `File` interface might be making things harder because if you just had `vector<File>` there wouldn't be problems. So, are you sure you need it? If in doubt, feel free to let us check.

Comment: @black for now the whole thing is just on a whiteboard, so the design can be freely changed. `File` is an interface mainly because I don't know how to make "polymorphic pimpl" (for lack of better term), and storing `offset` in `ZipFile` or, IDK, `crc` in `TarFile` sounds right, at least better than making a `std::map` in `ConcreteArchives`.

Comment: Writing sensible polymorphic classes is hard without taking their usage into account, after all these exhibit polymorphic behavior. If you give a bit more info on how these File types are used then we can probably be of more help.

Comment: At very least, I want to present the file names to the user. If it's available, I'd like also to present file sizes. The user should be able to select which files to extract. Possibly he should also be able to unpack one file "in memory" to get its content, but that is not much different from extracting.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, you can move the extracting interface from `Archive` to `File`. The archive will return `std::vector<File*>`, but in fact each object will be, e.g., `ZipFile`, and will know which archive it belongs to and what is its type, and will be able to call proper extract method.

As a result, you can have code without any checking of archive type:

```
struct File;
struct Archive {
    virtual std::vector<File*> fileList() = 0;
};

struct File {
    File(std::string name_) : name(name_) {}
    virtual void extract() = 0;
    std::string name;
};

struct ZipFile;
struct ZipArchive: public Archive {
    void extractFile(ZipFile& file);
    virtual std::vector<File*> fileList();
};

struct ZipFile: public File {
    ZipArchive* archive;
    virtual void extract() { archive->extractFile(*this); }
    ZipFile(std::string name_, ZipArchive* archive_) : File(name_), archive(archive_) {}
};
```

Full example: http://ideone.com/kAs5Jc

It can be more diffucult if you want to extract many files with one call, but you can have archive's `extractFile` just remember that file, and then a special method in the `Archive` class to extract all the remembered files at once. I think this can even be hidden under a rather simple interface.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ZipArchive` could search in its list of files for the passed pointer. If it's in there, it could either use the stored pointer (which already is of type `ZipFile`) or `static_cast` the passed pointer to `ZipFile` (because you have proven its type). If the passed pointer is not in the list, it's obviously not a file owned by this archive, so you can go on with error handling.

You could also add a backpointer of type `Archive*` to every `File`. The concrete `ZipArchive` implementation can than check if its one of its files by a simple pointer comparsion.

```
void ZipArchive::extract(std::vector<File*> files) 
{
    for (auto file : files)
    {
        if (file->archive() == this) 
        {
            // one of my files
            auto zipFile = static_cast<ZipFile*>(file);
            // do something with zipFile
        }
        else
        {
            // file is owned by some other archive
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds similar to @alediaferia's approach, except it uses pointers rather than random integers. I like this solution more as it leaves no room for ambiguity.

Comment: @rr The backpointer has two advantages though: 1. You don't need to maintain a list of unique integers; it's extensible. 2. You don't only make sure that the File has the correct type, you also make sure that it is a file of this archive with just a single comparsion.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Archive { 
public:
    static int registerArchiveType(const std::string &name) {
        // generate a unique int for the requested name archive type
        // and store it in a map or whatever
        return uniqueInt;
    }

    int archiveType() const;

protected: 
    Archive(int type) : _type(type) {}
private: 
    int _type;

public:
     virtual extract(std::vector<File*> files);

    // your implementation details
};

class File {
public:
    int archiveType() { return _archType; }
protected:

    // force implementations to pass the same type
    // they received from the call to Archive::registerArchiveType
    File() {}
    void setArchiveType(const std::string &archiveType) {
        // multiple calls to registerArchiveType return the
        // same identifier if passed the same string
        _archiveType = Archive::registerArchiveType(archiveType);
    }

private:
    int _archiveType;
};
```

Then in your `ZipArchive` implementation, in the `extract` method you can perform a **static_cast** rathern than a dynamic one if the int returned by `archiveType` is the same as the one registered for the Zip archive type.

```
static const char* ZIP_TYPE = "zip";

// specialize your ZipFile making sure
// you pass the correct archive type identifier
// in the constructor
class ZipFile {
public:
    ZipFile() : File() {
        setArchiveType(ZIP_TYPE);
    }
    // bla bla
};

void ZipArchive::extract(std::vector<File*> files) {
    for (int i = 0; i < files.count(); i++) {
        if (files[i]->archiveType() == Archive::registerArchiveType(ZIP_TYPE)) {
            ZipFile *zipFile = static_cast<ZipFile*>(files[i]);
            // do something with zipFile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Your inheritance design is correct to me. I'm only suggesting to "register" your implementations in order to be able to identify them through a integer rather than having to dynamic_cast'ing. I'd still keep your specialized `ZipFile`s implementation. Anyway, I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is though error-prone and even less safer than `dynamic_cast`, which will fail if the conversion can't be done.

Comment: The issue is still `int zipArchive = Archive::registerArchiveType("tar")` which will then blow up following operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze the way you will treat `Archive`s: do you need to have in some places some common behavior due to undetermined types or do you not? This will bring to two different design choices, so choose carefully.

---

As said in the comments, you don't seem to need the former.
Let `File` represent a file handle and `ZipFile`, `TarFile` be derivations thereof. Then, for each type of file let an `Archive` handle it.

```
struct ZipFile 
{        
     File handle; 
     // zip-specific implementation details 
};

struct TarFile
{ 
     File handle;
     // tar-specific implementation details
};

class ZipArchive
{
     public:
            std::vector<ZipFile> list() const; 
            void extract(std::vector<ZipFile>);         

     private:
             std::vector<ZipFile> archive;
};
```

And the same for `TarArchive`. There is no more need to handle ownership, pointers and so on; you also get strong type safety.

Comment: But now I'm unable to hold `Archive` in other parts of the project, such as GUI, without using `ZipArchive`. I'll be constructing each one of these depending on the archive contents.

Comment: @rr You can instantiate the objects conditionally instead of delegating that to RTTI.